What Excel formula to use to understand how many nightshift hours
I have shift start times in Column E and finish times in Column F. I need a formula that will look at the start and finish times and tell me how many hours worked that fall into the window 23:00 - 07:00
Shifts could either be overnight (e.g. 23:30 - 06:30), or start before 23:00 (e.g. 17:00 - 00:00) or start before 07:00 but finish after 07:00 (e.g. 05:00 - 15:00) so I need the formula to account for all scenarios
Also if possible, if the entirety of the shift falls within 23:00 - 07:00 and is over 6 hours, I need 0.5 subtracted from the total

Have you made any attempts for yourself so far? If so, what are they, where do you think they failed. Perhaps give some example data in form of Markdown Table.

See this for calculating time across midnight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78663289/4961700

Then consider using an if() to deal with the 0.5. Given a hint and a link so you can have a go.

So far I have used this which seems to work for shifts that started before 07:00 and ended after 07:00 for example, but doesn't work for overnight shifts: =IF(AND(E111<=F111, F111<="07:00"), (F111-E111)*24, IF(AND(E111<="07:00", F111>="23:00"), (MIN(F111, "07:00") - MAX(E111, "23:00"))*24, IF(AND(E111<="07:00", F111>"07:00"), ("07:00" - E111)*24, IF(AND(E111<"23:00", F111>"23:00"), (F111 - "23:00")*24, IF(AND(E111<="07:00", F111>"07:00"), ("07:00" - E111)*24, 0)))))

Here is some example data in a Markdown table with the Nightshift hours that I have calculated with the formula above
| Employee ID | Shift         | Start | Finish | Duration | Nightshift Hours |
| ----------- | ------------- | ----- | ------ | -------- | ---------------- |
| 12345678    | 14:30 - 23:00 | 14:30 | 23:00  | 8        | 0                |
| 12345679    | 05:00 - 13:30 | 05:00 | 13:30  | 8        | 2                |
| 12345677    | 23:30 - 06:30 | 23:30 | 06:30  | 6.5      | 0                |
The duration looks shorter than it should be because of 30 mins unpaid break
